# OS_tcp_connection_destination Unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, iphone

I am getting an error when I open my store window in game.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OS_tcp_connection_destination setVal:prevVal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf141d90'
```

Comment: [http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

Comment: have you implemented setVal:prevVal: method?

Comment: Good for you glad you told us now do you want to share the code where you are calling `setVal:prevVal:` so we might actually be able to help you? -1 and vote to close for the lack of information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unrecognized selector" error occurs when you are trying to call a method on an object that does not implement the method.

Check if you are implementing the:

```
OS_tcp_connection_destination setVal:prevVal:
```

method